# Restructure data with SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

Let's say I have a table like this

```
Store   |   Fruit   |   Quantity  
--------+-----------+-----------
Lincoln |  cherry   | 2  
Lincoln |  apple    | 3  
Lincoln |  pear     | 4  
Abe     |  cherry   | 1  
Abe     |  apple    | 2
```

I need an SQL query that would return this:

```
Store   | Cherry | Apple | Pear
--------+--------+-------+------
Lincoln | 2      | 2     | 4  
Abe     | 1      | 2     |
```

It's fine if the "cherry, apple, and pear" columns are "hardcoded" in the query but what would be ideal (not sure if that's possible) is if when a new fruit pops up in the data a new column would be created by the SQL query

Comment: What have you tried? Happy to help if you get stuck but this is not a code writing service

Comment: @MikePala, What did you try till now??

Comment: @Mikepala, You need a `pivot`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: In general, any specific SQL query will return results with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their names and data types. Outside of dynamic SQL of some sort, you're unlikely to get your "ideal". Any reason you need to do this pivot in the database as opposed to an application or report builder (whatever is *consuming* this result set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is only tagged with [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), this is standard SQL:

```
select store, 
       sum(case when fruit = 'Cherry' then quantity end) as cherry_count, 
       sum(case when fruit = 'Apple' then quantity end) as apple_count, 
       sum(case when fruit = 'Pear' then quantity end) as pear_count 
from the_Table
group by store;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using **MS SQL SERVER** use `pivot`.You can use the below query and replace the tablename with your tablename:

**MS SQL SERVER**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT [Store], [Fruit], [Quantity]
  FROM [Your-TableName]
) src
pivot
(
  SUM([Quantity])
  FOR [Fruit] IN (Cherry, Apple, Pear)
) piv;
```

Comment: This will probably only work in MS SQL but you can fake it in other environments using a cursor something like this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44672/how-to-create-a-table-in-mysql-with-automatic-numeration-of-columns

Comment: @PaulColdrey Thanks,I forgot to mention SQL server,added now.OP didn't mention the DBMS that's cause for confusion